# How to reset the order of words in a string

Tags: r, character

I have a character below:

```
ms<-"DC, MD, MA, Wash, Balt, Bos, x, y, z"
```

and I wish to reorder it like this:

```
ms<-"DC, Wash, MD, Balt, MA, Bos, x, y, z"
```

Since I want to repeat this many times for different characters but with the same logic I do not want to change it manually every time but with a general function. Supposing that its order is now **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9** I want to convert it to **1,4,2,5,3,6,7,8,9**. The character may have from 6 to any number of substances but I want the convertion to take place only to the first 6, the rest should stay untouchable. I tried something like `ms <- ms[1,4,2,5,3,6]` but with no result.

Comment: `ms` is a string (character vector length = 1), not a vector of length 6.

Comment: Keep `ms` as a vector, not as a single string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a custom order, then split the string, order and then `paste` the contents together

```
toString(strsplit(ms, ",\\s*")[[1]][c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)])
#[1] "DC, Wash, MD, Balt, MA, Bos"
```

It can also be done if the number of words in the string is less i.e. by capturing as a group and then rearranging the backreference in the replacement with `gsub`.  This becomes cumbersome once there are more words

```
gsub("^(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+)$", 
                   "\\1, \\4, \\2, \\5, \\3, \\6", ms)
```

#### Update

With the new example in OP's post, it is not clear what is general from the index pattern

```
v1 <- strsplit(ms, ",\\s*")[[1]]
toString(v1[c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7:length(v1))])
#[1] "DC, Wash, MD, Balt, MA, Bos, x, y, z"
```

---

If only the first 6 words to be rearranged, then instead of splitting up the whole string, it can be arranged within `gsub`

```
gsub("^(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+)(.*)$", 
         "\\1, \\4, \\2, \\5, \\3, \\6\\7", ms)
#[1] "DC, Wash, MD, Balt, MA, Bos, x, y, z"
```

Here, we capture the words within braces (`(\\w+)`) and the backreference looks for the order of the captured group. i.e. `\\1` will the first captured group, `\\4` the 4th one and so on.  The backreference for the last one (`\\7`) will include all the other characters after the 6th word.

Comment: What if there are more words?

Comment: @firmo23  If you check the first solution, it is splitting by words, it would take care of that.  Only thing is that you need to have a custom index that ranges to the number of words

Comment: so words 7 and 8 would remain in their initial position

Comment: @firmo23  You said that you had a custom order and the solution is based on what you said in the post.

Comment: @firmo23 If you meant that you have to order this every n number of words, then `library(stringi); toString(matrix(stri_extract_all_regex(ms, "\\w+")[[1]], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))`, but it was not clear from your post.

Comment: @firmo23  Sorry, I don't follow your general case.  updated the answer

Comment: the number of substances may be >6, with no limit. The convertion should take place only to first 6

Comment: @firmo23 Please check if the updated one fits your criteria

Answer (score 4):

We can use `word` function from `stringr` package which extracts words from a sentence according to the position given.

```
library(stringr)    
word(ms, c(1,4,2,5,3,6))

#[1] "DC,"   "Wash," "MD,"   "Balt," "MA,"   "Bos"
```

If we need them back as single string we can wrap them up in `paste` with `collapse = ""`

```
paste(word(ms, c(1,4,2,5,3,6)), collapse = "")

#[1] "DC,Wash,MD,Balt,MA,Bos"
```

Comment: @firmo23 I don't see any impact of the updated post on the answer. `changed_order <- c(1,4,2,5,3,6,7,8,9); word(ms, changed_order)` would still give you the expected answer ?